# Custom UICollection view layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to configure a collection view to have the following custom layout shown in the attached image: 
[image: Custom UICollectionView Layout]. Essentially, I want to be able to configure my collection view so it appears to be based off rows instead of columns. For example:

Row 1: 3 equally sized squares, each 1/3 the width of the screen

Row 2: 1 square that's 2/3 the width of the screen, and then 2 squares stacked on 
       top of each other that are each 1/3 the width of the screen.

Row 3: 1 rectangle that fills the width of the screen

Row 4: 2 equally sized squares, each 1/2 the width of the screen

I've gone through multiple `UICollectionViewLayout` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` tutorials, but have been unable to find the information I need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.

1. Precompute the location of all of the squares in your repeat in [prepareLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-preparelayout)
2. Return the height of your content by using the (repeat height) * (number of items in collection) / (number of items in repeat) + the height at the remainder in [collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize) (this means you should cache the content height for each item in step 1, but the height is not the height of that square (its the height of the tallest element in that row)
3. In [layoutAttributesForElementsInRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelementsinrec) you need to figure out what repeat row your rect starts in and what row of the repeat it ends in.  You then return all of the cached layout attributes for those rows from step 1, but you have to add back a y value equal to (repeat count) / (first item index) * (repeat height).

basically its a bunch of math but when you divide it into repeating sections, the problem becomes which repeat am I in (divide) and what element within that repeat do I need (modulus), and it's much easier to solve.

I did something similar to this but with multiple repeats that could be arranged in different orders and it took a few hours to get it working without any bugs.  Its a lot of math and very tedious.